# Can the Xcode linker deduplicate symbols in a merged binary?

Tags: xcode, static-linking, dynamic-linking, xcode-mergeable-libraries

## Intro

I'm trying to determine whether Xcode's new [Mergeable Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-your-project-to-use-mergeable-libraries) feature can remove duplicated symbols in a scenario where an app links to two dynamic frameworks which both link to the same static library, as follows:

```
|--App
  |--DynamicFramework1      
    |--StaticLibrary   
  |--DynamicFramework2      
    |--StaticLibrary <- the same library that DynamicFramework1 links to
```

## Project setup

Here are some details about the app's structure:

1. The static library is named `StaticLibrary`. It:

   - Contains a single Objective-C class named `SLClass1`
2. The first dynamic framework target is named `DynamicFramework1`. It:

   - Contains a single Objective-C class named `DF1Class1` that calls into `SLClass1`; and
   - Has a `MERGEABLE_LIBRARY` build setting value of `YES`.
3. The second dynamic framework target is named `DynamicFramework2`. It:

   - Contains a single Objective-C class named `DF2Class1` that calls into `SLClass1`; and
   - Has a `MERGEABLE_LIBRARY` build setting value of `YES`.
4. The app target is named `App`. It:

   - Contains a single Swift class named `ViewController` that calls into the `DF1Class1` and `DF2Class1` classes; and
   - Has a `MERGED_BINARY_TYPE` build setting value of `Automatic`.<sup>1</sup>

I've created a minimal Xcode project [here](https://github.com/ale-gen/mergeable-libraries) that has the above structure.

## Expected result

The merged app binary, when built it in Release mode, contains the symbols for `DF1Class1`, `DF2Class1` and `SLClass1` directly within it and it contains only one instance of each of these symbols (i.e. no duplicates).

I am basing this expectation on the [Benefits of mergeable libraries](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10268/?time=341) section of the [Meet mergeable libraries](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10268/) talk from WWDC 2023 where the speaker said:

> When merging, the linker can de-duplicate content, such as strings, across all libraries. For instance, it removes redundant symbol references, Objective-C selectors, and objc_msgsend stubs.

## Actual result

The merged app binary, when built it in Release mode, contains the symbols for `DF1Class1`, `DF2Class1` and `SLClass1` directly within it but it contains two instances of `SLClass1`'s symbols (i.e. it contains duplicates).<sup>2</sup>

## My Question

Have I missed something in the app's build settings or have I misunderstood the capability of Mergeable Libraries? Can I get the Xcode linker to deduplicate symbols in the app's merged binary?

## Footnotes

<sup><sup>1</sup>I have tried with a `MERGED_BINARY_TYPE` build setting value of `Manual` also but the result is the same.

<sup>2</sup>I have validated this by running the `nm` command on the app's executable file and inspecting the output.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's Quinn "The Eskimo" (renowned for his tireless support in the Apple Developer forums) has confirmed that Mergeable Libraries will not deduplicate symbols in the above scenario.

For the details, see his answer in the Apple Developer Forums [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/741545).

Comment: I edited the answer so it reads as a complete answer to the question and not as additional information. I voted for it to be un-deleted following the edit.